# How to Reduce Noise in a Video Stream?

Tags: noise, denoising, video-processing, video-compression, video

I've been using Open Broadcaster to stream the infrared HDMI output from a 4K Sony video camera. It works pretty well, but one thing that I'm finding a little annoying for image analysis is the presence of grayscale salt and pepper noise in the footage.

Does anyone know if there's a way I could reduce this? I've been trying to change the video bitrate (currently at 40,000), but are there potentially other things I could do (such as play with the downscale filter)? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, [Salt and Pepper Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt-and-pepper_noise) is done using [Median Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter).
There are variations of the [Non Local Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-local_means) to deal with Salt and Pepper but it might be overkill so I'd start with the above.

The tricky thing is to take advantage of having a Video and not just a static single image.
Hence you can also apply the filter in a temporal form.
If you use small kernel you might be able to pull it as it is.
For larger kernels you might need to use [Optical Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) to estimate which parts of the frame should be compared.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, I was hoping there might be something I could change with the bitrate of the stream or something that could potentially help before I have to apply a filter during processing.

Comment: @JackSimpson, could you please mark my answer?